# How to set a bluetooth device as my playback device without going to the device menu?

Tags: ios

I have some speakers that I would like to easily connect to when I arrive home and I'm already playing something on my device. Is there a way to easily set the device, when I arrive? Probably an automation script?

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts and automation are perfect for these kind of tasks. You first would need to create a shortcut that does all these actions and then using automation to trigger this shortcut.

The shortcut must contain the follwoing elements:

- turn the bluetooth on
- wait a couple seconds
- set the playback destination to your device (it must be connected and on, otherwise it won't appear on the list)

After the shortcut is set, set the personal automation task to run the shortcut when you arrive to the place.